# Space added inside text in UI part of Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've noticed that a space appears when I use `em()`, `strong()` and, apparently, `textOutput()` when they're inside a `p()` tag in the ui, or even if they're loose text. This is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  p("This is ", strong("bold"), ", and this is ", em("italic"), "."),
  br(),
  "Again, this is ", strong("bold"), ", and this is ", em("italic"), "."
)
```

There isn't anything on the server. The `textOutput()` example is a little longer, and it doesn't show anything new, so I left it out.

The output is this:

> This is **bold** , and this is *italic* .

> Again, this is **bold** , and this is *italic* .

As you can see, the comma and the period are separated by a space. This is really annoying – after all, punctuation marks don't have this in "proper" English, which is something I'd like to preserve in my Shiny App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.noWS` parameter.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("This is ", strong("bold", .noWS = c("after")), ", and this is ", em("italic"), "."),
  br(),
  "Again, this is ", strong("bold", .noWS = c("after")), ", and this is ", em("italic"), "."
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result:

```
This is bold, and this is italic .

Again, this is bold, and this is italic .
```